# How to get the parts of Elements?

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am now making structured data for a website of an event process, and the information on this website is as follows:

```
<div class="schedule">
  <p><span class="fwb">Date</span>: 22-Nov(Friday) 15:00-17:00</p>
  <p><span class="fwb">Location</span>: ABC Street</p>
</div>
```

I want to use the `getElement` method to create a variable for `startDate`

```
"startDate": "{{data}}" -->

"startDate": "2019-11-22T15:00"
```

I expect the output of 22-Nov (Friday) 15:00-17:00 to be 2019-11-22T15:00

```
"streetAddress": "{{data}}"  --->

"streetAddress": "ABC Street"
```

etc.

it is possible? Many Thanks

*Remark: I have no permission to change the source page because I am just a google tag manager admin

Answer (score 0):

We could do something like this ,

```
let startDate = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
console.log(new Date(startDate[0].innerText.replace(/.*Date:/,'')))
```

result:

```
 Fri Nov 23 2001 13:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

As you can see , the resultant data is inaccurate as the data which we fed to the new Date() function of JavaScript was incorrect.

if you want to convert a date / time format try to pass the accurate data first. your data currently misses the year.

If you still want the expected result we can hard code the year for now

```
let withYear = startDate[0].innerText.replace(/.*Date:/,'')
withYear  = withYear  + '2019'

console.log(new Date(withYear))
```

result :

```
Sat Nov 23 2019 13:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Cheers, happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Regex to find the date and address (Starts with : and ends with newline)
2. Convert date using toISOString() method

```js
let data=document.querySelector(".schedule").innerHTML
let patt=/:.*/
let startDate=data.split('</p>')[0].match(patt)[0].slice(2)
let address=data.split('</p>')[1].match(patt)[0].slice(2)
let date = new Date(startDate.slice(0,20)+new Date().getFullYear()); 
let isoDate = new Date(date.getTime() - (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString().slice(0,16);
document.querySelector(".output").innerHTML="StartDate=> {"+isoDate+"}<br/>Address=> {"+address+"}"
```

```html
<div class="schedule">
     <p><span class="fwb">Date</span>: 22-Nov(Firday) 15:00-17:00</p>
     <p><span class="fwb">Location</span>: ABC Street</p>
</div>    

<div class="output"></div>
```

Read more:

- Regular expressions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions
- ISO Date Conversion: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_toisostring.asp